# Delphi - how to check if a string contains a set format of characters

Tags: delphi

Im trying to sort my TV shows from my movies and I figured best way to do this would be to identify them vie the TV shows season and episode stamp.

all my TV shows have the following format S00E00.

tried the following

```
if (Pos(IntToStr(I), SR.Name) > 0) and (Pos('S', SR.Name) > 0) then
result := true;
```

but that didn't work because if a movie had a title Containing 's' and any number it would copy it across.

would need something like 
if string pos "letter s followed by integer , integer ,letter  e , integer , integer" then result := true

that was regardless if the episode is S01E03 or S09E12 will still copy.

.........................................

edited 12/22/2015

.........................................

Thanks Remy didn't think its would be that easy.

here is the procedure just to clarify.

```
procedure TForm7.TvShowCopy (Format: string);// Format would be .mp4 or whatever you're using but since the procedure searches for a name matching "S00E00" format I suppose you wouldn't need the format and could just use *.*. 

begin

  aTvshowFiles := TDirectory.GetFiles(STvshows,format,// aTVshowfiles  is a TStringDynArray , STvshows is the Source directory for the TV shows.
                   TSearchOption.soAllDirectories,
                   function(const Path: string; const SR: TSearchRec):Boolean
                   begin
                     result:= TRegEx.IsMatch(SR.Name, 'S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9]') 
                   end);
                     CopyFilesToPath(aTvshowFiles, DTvshows);
end;
```

tested and would appear to be working.

Comment: That sounds like a job for regular expressions.

Comment: What Delphi version? And where is the data being stored (in memory, in a database, or somewhere else)? You need to add more details. Please [edit] your question to do so instead of adding them via comments.

Comment: @KenWhite: `SR.Name` implies `TSearchRec` is likely being used, which would mean filename enumeration is being used.

Comment: @Remy: It shouldn't have to be inferred. If the poster is attempting to match filenames, it's very different than trying to match data in a database. The question would be improved for future readers if the poster edited to make it clear what was being asked. If the question is about matching filenames, then it shouldn't ask about checking a *string*; it should be asking about checking a *filename*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Ron mentioned in comments, you can use a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info):

```
uses
  ..., RegularExpressions;

function ContainsSeasonAndEpisode(const Input: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result := TRegEx.IsMatch(Input, 'S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9]'); // or: 'S\d\dE\d\d'
end;

...

Result := ContainsSeasonAndEpisode(SR.Name);
```

As Ken mentioned in comments, you can also use [`MatchesMask()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Masks.MatchesMask), such as if you are testing a filename:

```
uses
  ..., Masks;

function ContainsSeasonAndEpisode(const Input: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result := MatchesMask(Input, '*S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9]*');
end;

...

Result := ContainsSeasonAndEpisode(SR.Name);
```

Or, you can simply compare the input string manually instead, eg:

```
uses
  ..., StrUtils;

function ContainsSeasonAndEpisode(const Input: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result := false;
  Idx := Pos('S', Input);
  while Idx <> 0 do
  begin
    if (Idx+5) > Length(Input) then
      Exit;

    if (Input[Idx+1] >= '0') and (Input[Idx+1] <= '9') and
       (Input[Idx+2] >= '0') and (Input[Idx+2] <= '9') and
       (Input[Idx+3] = 'E') and
       (Input[Idx+4] >= '0') and (Input[Idx+4] <= '9') and
       (Input[Idx+5] >= '0') and (Input[Idx+5] <= '9') then
    begin
      Result := true;
      Exit;
    end;

    Idx := PosEx('S', Input, Idx+1);
  end;
end;

...

Result := ContainsSeasonAndEpisode(SR.Name);
```

Comment: With the information that it's a search to match a filename in a specific pattern, *MatchesMask* might also be an alternative - it supports pseudo regex-type pattern matching.